# Learning multivariate techniques to analyze the gut microbiome

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis

I would like to start learning some of the basics regarding data processing and analysis of microbiome data using R.

Can anyone recommend a tutorial on some of the core/basic approaches that also include publicly available microbiome data sets?

(Note: I understand that this would probably be highly dependent upon the questions that I want to ask about the microbiome, but surely there are fundamentals related to this type of data analysis that I could start to learn.) Thanks!

Comment: I had good luck using the vegan package in R when I was doing multivariate stats. Lots of documentation (vignettes), etc - though of course you didn't say that you're looking to use R. I imagine anything you'd generally want to do related to gut flora would be essentially community ecology, which is what the package was built for.

Comment: Whoops! I forget that this site isn't specifically for R. That's what I'm looking for, so will update my question. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

We have a paper titled Hypothesis Testing and Power Calculations for Taxonomic-Based Human Microbiome Data' that might be helpful:

http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0052078